# PHP/JQuery contact form not emailing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have a simple contact form

```
<form role="form" id="contactForm" method="post" action="php/mailer.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-effect" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control form-effect" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea type="textarea" class="form-control form-effect" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sub" id="sbtBtn">Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="form-messages"></div>
```

When the form is submitted, my javascript file acts on its submit

```
var form = $('#contactForm');
var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

$(form).submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = $(form).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        data: formData,
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(response) {
        $(formMessages).text(response);
        $(form)[0].reset();
    }).fail(function(data) {
        if (data.responseText !== '') {
            $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
        } else {
            $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
        }
    });
});
```

This then calls my php file mailer.php

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    $to_email = "test@gmail.com";
    $name      = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email     = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $message   = filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if(strlen($name)<2){ // If length is less than 2 it will output JSON error.
        json_encode('Name is too short or empty!');
    }
    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //email validation
        json_encode('Please enter a valid email!');
    }

    $message_body = $message."\r\n\r\n-".$name."\r\nEmail : ".$email."\r\n (".$message.") " ;

    $headers = 'From: '.$name.'' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: '.$email.'' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $send_mail = mail($to_email, "Contact from website", $message_body, $headers);

    if(!$send_mail) {
        json_encode('Could not send mail! Please try again.');
    }else{
        json_encode("Thank you for your message, we will contact you shortly");
    }
}
```

For some reason, the output I get displayed is null, and no email is sent.  I have been trying to figure out why but can't seem to find anything.  I know it gets into the PHP file, but not sure what problem it is having.

I dont even know where it is getting the null output from?

Comment: Have you looked in the error logs?

Comment: Where do you actually output anything to the page?

Comment: Why are you `json_encode()`ing your response messages? Don't you want to display those instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you need to put `echo` before all you json_encodes like

```
echo json_encode('Name is too short or empty!');
```

Then at least you can see if any of your validation messages are triggering.

Second, you need to try a php file with just a mail() command and hard coded parameters to confirm that your mail is set up correctly.  If you're working on localhost, it's likely that it's not.

Next, check in your console (f12) under network and confirm that the data you want is actually being submitted.  you should see one of your json responses as the response.

By now, you should have a better idea of where to focus your efforts/questions

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to add echo before each json_encode()